# Optimizing Ungunzipping process in Java?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, compression, gunzip

I have a problem with the time it requires for .gz files to get uncompressed using the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class UnGunzipClass{

    public static boolean ungunzip(String compressedFile, String decompressedFile){

        try{

            // in
            FileInputStream fileIn          = new FileInputStream(compressedFile);
            GZIPInputStream gZipIn          = new GZIPInputStream(fileIn);
            BufferedInputStream in          = new BufferedInputStream(gZipIn);

            // out
            FileOutputStream fileOut        = new FileOutputStream(decompressedFile);
            BufferedOutputStream out        = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut);

            int n = 0;
            int len = 1024*1024*1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];

            while((n = in.read(buffer,0,len)) > 0){
                out.write(buffer,0,n);
            }

            gZipIn.close();
            fileOut.close();

            return true;

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: files are up to 100MB, but it is still taking me tens of minutes to run, so I am trying to get something faster. Speed is good :)

Comment: Do you really need a 1GB memory buffer (not that it should matter speedwise)?

Comment: `n = in.read(buffer,0,n)`. That last `n` seems wrong. should be `buffer.length`.

Comment: Does this even work? If you start with `n=0`, according to the docs, it should not read any bytes and exit your loop.

Comment: @Thilo, you are right. Should be `n = in.read(buffer,0,len))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created your `BufferedInputStream` from the `GZIPInputStream`, for performance you would do that in the reverse order. Also, I suggest you shrink your buffer size (and use your buffered streams). Finally, I would use a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and that might look something like

```
public static boolean ungunzip(String compressedFile,
        String decompressedFile) {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32768;
    try (InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(compressedFile)), BUFFER_SIZE);
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(decompressedFile), BUFFER_SIZE)) {
        int n = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((n = in.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is still slow, but I guess this is as fast as it gets :) thanks!